# How to search chinese characters with Solr?

Tags: search, drupal, solr

Basically I'm working on Drupal & using Solr as search engine. It searches some of the simplified chinese word/characters & some not like below

美国：为美朝峰会同朝鲜进行的磋商取得进展

It's not searching as simple character.

So I gone through both

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/language-analysis.html
http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Solr_-_configuration_for_Chinese_and_correct_results_for_german_umlauts

& in solr config file I have below

```
<fieldType name="text_chinese" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.smart.SmartChineseAnalyzer"/>
  <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.HMMChineseTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
              words="org/apache/lucene/analysis/cn/smart/stopwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

It's giving

> local:
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Could not load conf for core local: Plugin init failure for
>   [schema.xml] fieldType "text_chinese": Cannot load analyzer:
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.smart.SmartChineseAnalyzer. Schema file
>   is /var/solr/cores/local/conf/schema.xml

still it's not giving result.

Not sure if missing something in config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is telling you that Solr isn't able to find the implementing class of the analyzer you have defined - `Cannot load analyzer: org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.smart.SmartChineseAnalyzer`.

The SmartCN analyzer isn't loaded by default, but it's included in the binary build under `contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs/lucene-analyzers-smartcn-<version number>.jar`.

[Add the directory to the list of directories that Solr can load libraries from](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/lib-directives-in-solrconfig.html) in solrconfig.xml:

```
<lib dir="../../../contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs" regex=".*smartcn.*\.jar" />
```